# how can Rss Location Based Feed be implemented

Tags: java, rss, location, feed, rss-reader

After more than 10 Hours of searching the web, I am not able to find a single piece of information that shows me how to implement RSS feeds based on location. Also, how can I implement Location and Category-based RSS Feed Search in Java, similar to Groupon and Living Social sites? I want to show location-based deals. Any help would be greatly appreciated.